# Amazon AWS DynamoDB converting List of Map to ArrayList of objects

Tags: list, amazon-web-services, dictionary, arraylist, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to learn DynamoDB from Amazon AWS,and have been able to retrieve data with success, however I am having a hard time converting it to usable form.

My goal is to convert the result to an ArrayList of my Data data type, which is a ValueObject class with attributes, getters and setters.

Thanks!

```
Map<String,String> expressionAttributesNames = new HashMap<>();
expressionAttributesNames.put("#network_asset_code","network_asset_code");
expressionAttributesNames.put("#temperature","temperature");

Map<String,AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
expressionAttributeValues.put(":network_asset_codeValue", new AttributeValue().withS("17AB05"));
expressionAttributeValues.put(":temperature", new AttributeValue().withN("21"));

ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
   .withTableName("things")
   .withFilterExpression("#network_asset_code = :network_asset_codeValue and #temperature = :temperature")
   .withExpressionAttributeNames(expressionAttributesNames)
   .withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues);


ScanResult scanResult = client.scan(scanRequest);

List<Map<String,AttributeValue>> attributeValues = scanResult.getItems();
ArrayList<Data> dataArray = new ArrayList<>();

for (Map map: attributeValues) {
     Data d = map.values();
     dataArray.add(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I could get it right:

```
for (Map map: attributeValues) {

            AttributeValue attr = (AttributeValue) map.get("network_asset_code");

            Data d = new Data();
            d.network_asset_code = attr.getS();

            dataArray.add(d);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DynamoDBMapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html) to automagically convert DynamoDB items to Java objects (POJO) using [annotations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html).